# Javascript how to narrow down suitable URL in the if statment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to develop a Javascript code which will suit my website. Here is my code:

```js
jQuery('.hestia-title').click(function() {
  var link;
  link = location.href;
  if (link = "http://www.puslapioguru.eu" || "https://www.puslapioguru.eu" || "www.puslapioguru.eu") {
    var element_to_scroll_to = jQuery('.second-title')[0];
    console.log("Viskas veikia");
    element_to_scroll_to.scrollIntoView();
  } else {
    window.location.href = "http://www.puslapioguru.eu/";
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This code should determine on what open page it is run, but I encounter a problem with the if statement:

```js
if (link="http://www.puslapioguru.eu" || "https://www.puslapioguru.eu" || "www.puslapioguru.eu")
```

I want that the if statement would run only if the specific URL would be opened, but now it even runs if the opened page URL is "http://www.puslapioguru.eu/temu-portfolio/". Can someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: You're assigning a value to `link` in your `if` condition, there's no [comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). Also, that's not how [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) work.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Comment: @Kurzalead How is the linked article related to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each part of `||` (or `&&`) has to equate to true/false by itself, ie:

```
 if ((true|false) || (true||false))
```

so, rather than just use a string, you need to provide something to compare with, in *each* of the parts around the `||`

Secondly, in javascript, if you are comparing a value you need to use `==` or `===`, not `=`.  This gives,

```
link = location.href;
if (link == "http://www.puslapioguru.eu" 
      || link == "https://www.puslapioguru.eu" 
      || link == "www.puslapioguru.eu") {
```

You can make this more flexible, but these are the essential **issues** with your `if`.

---

In this case you might want just `location.host` instead of `location.href` as `.href` is the entire address including any page path or parameters while `.host` already removes the `https://` etc parts for you:

```
link = location.host;
if (link == "www.puslapioguru.eu") {
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use a *Regular Expression*

```
/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?puslapioguru\.eu$/i.test(link); // Exactly on this
// OR
/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?puslapioguru\.eu(?:$|\/)/i.test(link); // Any path on this
```

Or use *Array methods* to test for your options

```
const permittedSiteList = [
    'http://www.puslapioguru.eu',
    'https://www.puslapioguru.eu',
    'www.puslapioguru.eu'
];
permittedSiteList.includes(link); // eactly one of these
// OR
permittedSiteList.some(
    domain => (link + '/').toLowerCase().startsWith(domain + '/')
); // Any path
```

---

If you choose one of these, I also recommend abstracting the *RegExp* or the *Array* outside the condition so it is more readable; i.e. the `if`'s condition looks like

```
if (permittedSiteRegExp.test(link)) {
    // ...
}
// OR
if (permittedSiteList.includes(link)) {
    // ...
}
// OR in the Array + any path case, also the test function
const isThisDomain = domain => (link + '/').toLowerCase().startsWith(domain + '/');
if (permittedSiteList.some(isThisDomain)) {
    // ...
}
```

---

Currently, you're performing an assignment in your `if` statement so you'll get unexpected behaviour